# Controling distribution of bolts in Storm?

Tags: apache-storm

I have an EvaluationBolt (for e.g. memory monitoring) and I want to make sure one executor for it runs on every worker process (which in my case is one per physical node, i.e. supervisor.slots.ports is configured to only port 6700). On the topic I found this question:

[How bolts and spouts are shared among workers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20313177/how-bolts-and-spouts-are-shared-among-workers)

But it does not state how and if I myself can control distribution of bolts and spouts. Can one somehow configure the scheduler manually?

Cheers,
Tomi

Answer (score 3):

The complicated and correct route is to write a Storm scheduler: http://xumingming.sinaapp.com/885/twitter-storm-how-to-develop-a-pluggable-scheduler/.

What I've also found is that the Storm scheduler by default performs round-robin scheduling between hosts, so most of the time you can just use the built-in scheduler to distribute your tasks equally over all hosts.